# How to automatically populate a blade field from an eloquent model relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

### Synopsis

I have two models with a M:M relationship through a pivot table.  A `User` model and a `Group` model - many user's could belong to many groups - vice-versa.

How can I automatically populate my multi-select within blade?  Also, is it really necessary to have to always implement `$user->groups()->lists('id')`?

### My current snippet (works - but IMO is nasty)

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('groups', 'Groups') }}
    {{ Form::select('groups[]', $groups, Input::old('groups', $user->groups()->lists('id')), ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']) }}
</div>
```

Comment: How you are passing he data to the model ?

Comment: `$user->groups()->sync(Input::get('groups', []));` is executed in my postSave action.  I load the model with: `User::with('groups')->findOrFail($userId);` - where `$userId` is parsed via a route as a parameter.

Comment: So you want to automate the population or this is not working ?

Comment: Yes - I would like to automate the population, which is not working - unless I manually do this: `Input::old('groups', $user->groups()->lists('id'))` inside the `Form::select()`

Comment: You have to use this code in your view but you can automate the data insertion into the view.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha cheers for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

To automate the populating of the `multi select` in the `view` you can create a `View::composer()` which will pass the data to the view automatically every tine you load the view. You can create such a View::composer using something like this:

```
View::composer('viewname', function($view)
{
    $user = User::with('groups')->findOrFail($userId);
    $view->with('user', $user);
});
```

Now every time you load that view iusing something like this:

```
return VIew::make('viewname');
```

The data (`$user`) will be passed to the view (`viewname`) and if you have the code to populate the `multi-select` in your view then it'll be populated automatically. In the view you may use something like this:

```
{{ 
    Form::select(
        'groups[]',
        $user->groups,
        Input::old('groups', $user->groups()->lists('id')),
        ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']
    )
}}
```